# How would I switch to a new activity using an ArrayAdapter, ListView, and a Menu adds items based on User Input

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

An app I am designing is based around a Menu whose items are created by the user typing into an EditText and then submitting the text by Button click. I also want to be able to go to a new activity based on the user clicking the menu item that they created. Here is my Java code so far:

```
    package com.example.doodlestudy;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private OnClickListener AddToString;

Button Badd;
EditText ETadd;
ListView LVmain;

String filename = "Main_Activity";
String input;
FileOutputStream outputStream;

ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Badd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Badd);
    ETadd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETadd);
    LVmain = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LVmain);

    m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_listItems);
    LVmain.setAdapter(m_adapter);

    Badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            input = ETadd.getText().toString();

            m_listItems.add(new String(input));
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        }
    });

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    }
```

Here is my xml code:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETadd"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Click to Edit..." >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Badd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LVmain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.doodlestudy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.doodlestudy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have yet to touch my manifest because I can't get my code to allow for a transition to a new activity. I am thinking I might need a different way to store the string that the user creates in the EditText, but I am not positive.

Comment: can you please let us know what purpose will the list view  be serving, as i thought your requirement is to create new dynamic menu items, and on click on these newly created menu items, you should be navigating to a new Activity.. right? Correct em if i am wrong

Comment: This is correct, I want to go to a new activity based on the item clicked.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like what you want is to set up a `ClickListener` for your `ListView`, much like your button, which takes you to the next `Activity`. This is what it looks like:

```
        LVmain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
//              intent.putExtra(name, value);
//              take the time to put extra information that you need for the next activity here
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Then your manifest needs to be made aware of your new activity as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.doodlestudy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.doodlestudy.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="SecondActivity"></activity> 
        // add your activities to your manifest
    </application>
```